# Using option for bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to write with the BioMed Central template.

For the bibliotraphy, I have a file named:

```
bmc_article.bib
```

In the main `.tex`, the bibliography is included by:

```
% if your bibliography is in bibtex format, use those commands:
\bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys} % Style BST file
\bibliography{bmc_article}      % Bibliography file (usually '*.bib' )
```

In the `bmc-mathphys.sty` the following commands appear:

```
\DeclareOption{undef}    {\only@first{\def\bibliography@style{0}\def\bibliography@key{undef}
                          \def\bibliography@style@name{undefined}}} 
\DeclareOption{basic}    {\only@first{\def\bibliography@style{1}\def\bibliography@key{basic}
                          \def\bibliography@style@name{Basic Springer}}} 
\DeclareOption{chemistry}{\only@first{\def\bibliography@style{2}\def\bibliography@key{chemistry}
                          \def\bibliography@style@name{Chemistry}}} 
\DeclareOption{bmc}      {\only@first{\def\bibliography@style{10}\def\bibliography@key{bmc}
                          \def\bibliography@style@name{BMC Reference Style}}}
```

I guess I need the "`bmc`" style, but how can I select that option? Where should I select it?

Answer (score 6):

There should be a call

```
\usepackage[bmc]{bmcart-biblio}
```

in the document preamble.

Here's a test document, using the files in the distribution.

```
\documentclass[linenumbers,draft]{bmcart}
\usepackage[bmc]{bmcart-biblio}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\get#1\p@{#1}
\count@=\expandafter\get\leftarea@width
\advance\count@\@ne
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\leftarea@width{\the\count@\p@}}\x
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\set@numberlines@box{\rlap}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support

%%% Put your definitions there:
\startlocaldefs
\endlocaldefs


%%% Begin ...
\begin{document}

%%% Start of article front matter
\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{fmbox}
\dochead{Research}

\title{A sample article title}

\author[
   addressref={aff1},                   % id's of addresses, e.g. {aff1,aff2}
   corref={aff1},                       % id of corresponding address, if any
   noteref={n1},                        % id's of article notes, if any
   email={jane.e.doe@cambridge.co.uk}   % email address
]{\inits{JE}\fnm{Jane E} \snm{Doe}}
\author[
   addressref={aff1,aff2},
   email={john.RS.Smith@cambridge.co.uk}
]{\inits{JRS}\fnm{John RS} \snm{Smith}}

\address[id=aff1]{%                           % unique id
  \orgname{Department of Zoology, Cambridge}, % university, etc
  \street{Waterloo Road},                     %
  %\postcode{}                                % post or zip code
  \city{London},                              % city
  \cny{UK}                                    % country
}
\address[id=aff2]{%
  \orgname{Marine Ecology Department, Institute of Marine Sciences Kiel},
  \street{D\"{u}sternbrooker Weg 20},
  \postcode{24105}
  \city{Kiel},
  \cny{Germany}
}

\begin{artnotes}
\note[id=n1]{Equal contributor} % note, connected to author
\end{artnotes}

\end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout

\begin{abstractbox}

\begin{abstract} % abstract
\parttitle{First part title} %if any
Text for this section.

\parttitle{Second part title} %if any
Text for this section.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\kwd{sample}
\kwd{article}
\kwd{author}
\end{keyword}

\end{abstractbox}

\end{frontmatter}

\section*{Content}

Text and results for this section, as per the individual journal's instructions for authors. 
\nocite{*}

\begin{backmatter}

\section*{Competing interests}
  The authors declare that they have no competing interests.

\section*{Author's contributions}
    Text for this section \ldots

\section*{Acknowledgements}
  Text for this section \ldots

\bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys} % Style BST file
\bibliography{bmc_article}      % Bibliography file (usually '*.bib' )

\end{backmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To get this package, should i write it in latex preamble?

Comment: @faiza Yes, that's its place.

Comment: but still, my file doesnt show the references in this format...

Comment: @faiza Thanks, I don't know how the call came out wrongly written.