# bmc-mathphys - how to generate a nameyear citation?

Tags: bibliographies

Here's my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys}
\begin{document}
\nocite{JEF_5G}
\bibliography{my_ref}
\end{document}
```

Below is bib:

```
@PREAMBLE{}

@String { AER  = {American Economic Review} }
@String { JIMF = {Journal of International Money and Finance} }


@Article{JEF_5G,
  Title                    = {What Will {5G} Be?},
  Author                   = {Jeffrey G. Andrews and Stefano Buzzi and Wan Choi and Stephen Hanly and Angel Lozano and Anthony C. K. Soong and Jianzhong Charlie Zhang},
  Journal                  = {IEEE J. Sel. Areas Commun., Special Issue on 5G Communication Systems},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Note                     = {{{doi}: 10.1109/JSAC.2014.2328098}},
  Number                   = {6},
  Pages                    = {1065-1081},
  Volume                   = {32},

  Owner                    = {kenadams},
  Timestamp                = {2014.08.14}
}
```

Comment: Your MWE is incomplete, see [Using option for bibliography style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156833/using-option-for-bibliography-style)

Comment: Or not perhaps. I'm not familiar either with this bibliography style or document class, but managed to get author-year citation nevertheless. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from `bmc-mathphys.bst`:

> ```
> % Settings:
> % It's possible to pass few options to bibtex style via @settings reference. 
> % To validate options, need to write that reference (@settings) citeing key (f.e: \citation{foo}) 
> % to aux file. From tex file it can be done with \nocite{} command.
> %
> % Examples:
> %     1) To make unsorted bibliography (bibs listed as cited)  
> %         a) write to bib file:
> %             @settings{label, options="unsort"}
> %         b) write in tex file \nocite{label}
> %     
> %     2) To make author-year bibliography
> %         a) write to bib file:
> %             @settings{label, options="nameyear"}
> %         b) write in tex file \nocite{label}
> %     
> %     3) To make alphanumerical unsorted bibliography (bibs listed as cited)  
> %         a) write to bib file:
> %             @settings{label, options="alpha,unsort"}
> %         b) write in tex file \nocite{label}
> % 
> % By default, style produces unsorted bibliography.
> ```

Following the instructions under 2), I get with your MWE: 
[image: MWE compiled]

However, `LuaLaTeX` produces a non-fatal error. You haven't specified what (bibliography) compiler you are using, so I haven't investigated further.

Comment: I'm using a WinEDT.

Comment: @jeecabz `WinEDT` is a (LaTeX editor)[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides]. I was wondering what compiler you use, when you want to produce the final document (usually DVI od pdf). Some of the popular options are: `pdfLaTeX`, `XeTeX`,  `LuaLaTeX`.
Additionally, have you tried my solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: I used pdflatex then bibtex in generating bbl file..

Comment: @jeecabz I see. So does the following MWE work for you:
    `\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys}

    \begin{document}
     Here \cite{JEF_5G}
     \nocite{label}
     \bibliography{my_ref}
    \end{document}`
AFTER adding `@settings{label, options="unsort"}` to your .bib file?

Comment: Now, I found out.. %%%%% setting default options
FUNCTION {set.default.opt}
{"nameyear" 'list.string :=}

Comment: Changing the default option should indeed work as well.

Comment: I get this working, but then I have two warning messages: (1) There were undefined citations; (2) Citation `label' undefined. I wonder what to do to avoid the warnings.

Comment: @Aryo, that was probably because of \nocite{label}? I would simply ignore these warnings.

Comment: @Fato39, yes I think so too. The compiler pointed the command, which causes the warning, is `\nocite{label}`. Because in the bib file there is no citation entry that labelled `label`. For now, I ignored the warnings.